# How to get the application name in laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have set the application name using

```
php artisan app:name xyz
```

How can I progmatically access the application name in laravel ?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

From laravel version 5.3^ there is a function to call the app name

```
config('app.name');
```

You can change the default name 'Laravel' inside this file

```
config/app.php

'name' => 'Laravel',
```

And also inside .env file

```
APP_NAME=your_app_name
```

for latter to work, in config/app.php the line where you set the name should be written like this: `'name' => env('APP_NAME', 'fallback_app_name'),`

Comment: This works for me but I also had to restart **The PHP development Server** in order to apply changes.

Comment: Yes... if the change is made only in .env file then you have to restart the apache/nginx or restart the `php artisan serve` command, because the .env file is cached!

Comment: Can you post the link on that tutorial?

Comment: You can clear the Config cache without restarting with `php artisan config:clear`

Answer (score 8):

There's [`Illuminate\Console\AppNamespaceDetectorTrait`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.0/src/Illuminate/Console/AppNamespaceDetectorTrait.php) which you can use. Add this in your class:

```
class MyClass {

    use \Illuminate\Console\AppNamespaceDetectorTrait;
```

And then you can use it anywhere in that class with `$this->getAppNamespace()`

Answer (score 3):

If you want to get this variable form .env file:

```
//.env

APP_NAME=My appication name from .env file

APP_ENV=local
```

You get that way:

```
config('app.name')
```

If you want to get another variable, for example APP_ENV, just write:

```
config('app.local')
```

Answer (score 1):

To get application namespace:

```
use Illuminate\Container\Container;
Container::getInstance()->getNamespace();
```

To get application name:

```
config('app.name');
```

Comment: but ... on reddit reposting gives you sweet sweet karma! :D

Comment: @Nima which answer mentions the way to get the app namesapce without using a trait?