# How to rename a project in Laravel 7

Tags: laravel, rename, laravel-artisan, laravel-7

All results from searching the web offer to run the "php artisan app:name {newProjectName} but since Laravel 6 the app:name command has been removed.  So what is the way to do it in Laravel 7?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30046823/how-to-get-the-application-name-in-laravel/42250849#42250849

Answer (score 3):

You can rename your project editing the "app.php" at: **/laravel-project/config/app.php**

> ```
> /*
> |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
> | Application Name
> |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
> |
> | This value is the name of your application. This value is used when the
> | framework needs to place the application's name in a notification or
> | any other location as required by the application or its packages.
> |
> */
>
> 'name' => env('APP_NAME', 'Laravel'), // "Here your new Project Name"]; ?>
> ```

Remove the **env('APP_NAME','Laravel')** and replace it for your new Project Name 

 *It is recommended to remove the .env and use only the app.php file,  or protect the .env file in your .htaccess if your project are in production, there is a possibility to be downloaded from the browser.*

[See screenshot of the app.php file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vdNMM.png)

***Additional Info***

After this process please run the following command in your terminal:

```
php artisan optimize
php artisan config:clear
php artisan config:cache
```

Comment: Thank you but I am still confused. I initially created my first project calling it "blog" with the command "laravel new blog".  This created a folder "blog" on the root of my webserver.  I want to rename the folder to "new_name".  What confuses me is that in .ENV or app.php file the APP_Name is "Laravel" not "blog".  So must I change these 2 instances to "new_name" and then rename my folder?

Comment: @PaulGodard You can change the folder name whatever you want, and then if want you also can change the name of your poject like I posted above.
I recommed you to clear the cache and routes after this process.
At the terminal witth the follow commands: php artisan optimize and php artisan config:clear or php artisan config:cache

Comment: Thank you.  It seemed to work... although  I got an error with optimize... is that critical? Unable to prepare route [api/user] for serialization. Uses Closure. at vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php:1081

Comment: @PaulGodard Go to /project/routes/api.php and comment or remove routes with closure like https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/routing if you use routes here try to use with controllers not with functions. Then try again, should work now ;)

Answer (score 2):

### Rename the App

If you just want to rename your Laravel App you can do so in the `.env` file and change the `APP_NAME`

### Change the Namespace

Prior to version 6.0 the app:name command allowed to change the application **namespace**. This feature was removed however, you can read more about it [here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/27575).

If you really need this feature, there is a [community package for version 6](https://github.com/andrey-helldar/laravel-app), but none for version 7 that I could find.

### Create New

From the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/installation):

```
laravel new blog
```

or

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog
```

Answer (score 1):

please change name form laravel to your app

`'name' => env('APP_NAME', 'Laravel'),`

or change config/app.php

`'name' => env('APP_NAME', 'Laravel'),`

and

`php artisan config:cache`